# How to comprehend "no way to make a ‘conceptual is-a’ relationship without inheritance"?Could anyone make it clear by some simple example?

Tags: c++, objective-c

> A per the
>   documetation(https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/objective-c#objective-c-and-inherit),
>   which says: This is a major difference with Objective-C, where there
>   is only one form of inheritance (C++ provides private inheritance to
>   mean “share the code but don’t conform to the interface”, and public
>   inheritance to mean “kind-of”). The Objective-C language proper (as
>   opposed to coding practice) allows you to have the effect of “hiding”
>   an inherited method by providing an override that calls the “does not
>   understand” method. Furthermore Objective-C allows a conceptual “is-a”
>   relationship to exist apart from the inheritance hierarchy (subtypes
>   don’t have to be derived classes; e.g., you can make something that
>   is-a Stack yet doesn’t inherit from class Stack).
>
> **In contrast, C++ is more restrictive about inheritance: there’s no way
>   to make a “conceptual is-a” relationship without using inheritance
>   (the C++ work-around is to separate interface from implementation via
>   ABCs)**. The C++ compiler exploits the added semantic information
>   associated with public inheritance to provide static typing.

**I really could not get the idea.I think make a "conceptual is-a” relationship" is by combination.
So, where goes wrong?Could anyone make it clear by some simple example?**

Comment: It is possible to implement a conceptual "is-a" relationship using composition.    However, in C++ at least, it is *much much easier* to use inheritance, particularly if the derived class is a specialisation of the base class (e.g. a `Dog` is an `Animal`, does all the generic things an `Animal` does, but does them differently than other animals (like `Cat` or `Snake`).   Composition is typically easier to use than inheritance for "contains" or "has" or "consists of the set of' relationships  (e.g. a `Dog` has a number of `Leg`s).

Comment: Glad to see you again.Thank you for the clarification.